# Как убрать подсветку вокруг активного EditText?

Tags: android

Как убрать стандартную подсветку вокруг активного EditText? и при нажатии кнопки, хотелось бы чтобы она не выделялась у меня стандартным синим цветом. Какие свойства нужно для этого изменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается с помощью кастомных стилей (ColorState). Надо сначала определить свой стиль, типа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_red" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_pressed_red" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_selected_red" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_selected_red" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_red" />
</selector>
```

Далее в EditText делаем ссылку на него:

```
<EditText android:background="@drawable/my_edittext_style_states"/>
```

В принципе можно изменять то же самое и программно. Читать [здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)